# Using a multidimensional array to create input elements

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a list of `<input>` elements and I am trying to simplify it so the code is tidier and cleaner. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
if($row['replies'] == '1') {
   echo'<input type="submit" value="Locked">';
}else{
   echo'<input type="submit" value="Lock">';
}
if($row['flagged'] == '1') {
   echo'<input type="submit" value="Ignore">';
}
if($row['deleted'] == '1') {
   echo'<input type="submit" value="Deleted">';
}else{
   echo'<input type="submit" value="Delete">';
}
<input type="submit" value="Hello">
<input type="submit" value="Goodbye">
```

I am trying to simplify this using a multidimensional array, but I can't quite get my head around it. This is what I've tried so far:

```
$options = array("Lock"=>array("replies","Locked"),"Ignore"=>"flagged","Delete"=>array("deleted","Deleted"),"Hello","Goodbye");
foreach($options as $option) {
   if(in_array($option[0], array('Lock','Deleted'), true) && $row[$option[1] == '1') {
      echo'<input type="submit" value="'.$option[2].'">';
   }else{
      echo'<input type="submit" value="'.$option[0].'">';
   }
}
```

Comment: try foreach($array as $key=>$value)
That will allow you to use the #key (which can be flagged, deleted etc.)

Comment: unless I'm going crazy you've got a typo here `if(in_array($option[0], array('Lock','Deleted'), true) && $row[$option[1] == '1')`, you're missing a closing `]` on the last check, I _think_ it should be `if(in_array($option[0], array('Lock','Deleted'), true) && $row[$option[1]] == '1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$submit_values =
[
    $row['replies'] == '1' ? 'locked' : 'lock',
    $row['flagged'] == '1' ? 'ignore' : '',
    $row['deleted'] == '1' ? 'deleted' : 'delete',
    'hello',
    'goodbye'
];
$submit_values = array_filter($submit_values); // Remove any empty values.
foreach($submit_values as $value)
    printf ('<input type="submit" value="%s">', $value);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks this works and I really appreciate it! Just a few questions though... I was wondering why you didn't use `$submit_values = array(...)`, or are they both the same thing?

Comment: Yes they are the same thing.  Short array syntax has been available since version 5.4, (which has now been end of lifed http://php.net/eol.php).  All supported versions will work with the cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
$opts = array(
    "replies" => array("Lock", "Locked"),
    "flagged" => array(null, "Ignore"),
    "deleted" => array("Delete", "Deleted")
);

foreach ($opts as $key => $values) {
    if ($row[$key] == 1) {
        echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"{$values[1]}\">";
    } else {
        if ($values[0]) { 
            echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"{values[0]}\">";
        }
    }
}
```